# negative double zero not equal to zero?

Tags: c, double, equality, zero

I have a double `output` which is being printed as `-0.000000`

I have a loop that says:

```
if (output == 0) {
    printf("Continuing to go STRAIGHT.\n");
}
else if (output > 0) {
    printf("Turning LEFT.\n");
}
else if (output < 0) {
    printf("Turning RIGHT.\n");
}
```

This keeps printing the 3rd condition, saying that -0.000000 is less than 0. Why is this and how can I correct the issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's -0?  If you add `printf("output=%f\n",output);` immediately before these lines, what does it print?

Comment: Also, how is `output` being assigned?

Comment: Comparing floating point numbers using `==` is (basically) never going to work.

Comment: @dbush it prints -0.000000

Comment: @dbush output is a double which is equal to a steering correction algorithm output for a PID controller

Comment: What if you print with `%e`?

Comment: All floats are signed and `-0` is a valid result (e,.g.: with `sqrt(-0)`), you have to check for it. And please use the proper functions for comparing floats if available (like `isgreater()` et al. if `>=C99` is supported)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happen because the double representation in memory is not exact.
For example, `output` can be equal to -0.000000000000012, but `printf` only print the firsts digits.
You can try `printf("%.20lf", output);` to print more digits.

However, it is not a good practice to use the operator `==` with floating points.